# Compare Strings from between 2 files using Java

Tags: java, string-comparison

```
public class comparee {

static int count=0;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String a,b;

    FileReader fi = new FileReader(new File("C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Desktop\\SAM_PUBLIC_MONTHLY_20150802\\a.txt"));  // new file

    FileReader fii = new FileReader(new File("C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Desktop\\SAM_PUBLIC_MONTHLY_20150802\\b.txt"));  // new file

    BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(fi); //new

    BufferedReader br1 =new BufferedReader(fii); //old
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Desktop\\SAM_PUBLIC_MONTHLY_20150802\\samnew.txt"));

    int count = 0;
    while((a=br.readLine()) != null)
    {

        while((b=br1.readLine()) != null)
        {

            if(!(a.equals(b))) 
            {
                count++;
                fw.write(a);
            }

        }
        System.out.println(count);

    }


}
}
```

Hi, I am trying to compare string from a.txt and b.txt by reading line by line.
I would like to write the line on samdata.txt which is not available in a.txt but available on b.txt. would appreciate any help :) thanks

P.S the above code logic is incorrect

Comment: What is your ultimate goal with this exercise? Can you simply use the ubiquitous free command line [`diff`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility) utility?

Comment: It might be easier to read both files into `List`s and simply `removeAll` one from the other...

Comment: are your files sorted so that matched lines must be at the same position? Alternatively, for each line of a.txt the corresponding match in b.txt may be located anywhere? The solution may be quite different in each of these cases

Answer (score 0):

Comparing files is a complex operation, because you normally would have to look ahead in both files in order to find the next matching lines.

Now, if you are absolutely(!) sure that b.txt contains all the lines from a.txt, in the same order as a.txt, but has extra lines inserted at various places, then the following **might** be ok.

BTW: Your variable names are confusing, so I'm renaming them and using try-with-resources to ensure the readers and the writer get closed.

```
File fileA = new File("C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Desktop\\SAM_PUBLIC_MONTHLY_20150802\\a.txt");
File fileB = new File("C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Desktop\\SAM_PUBLIC_MONTHLY_20150802\\b.txt");
File fileNew = new File("C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Desktop\\SAM_PUBLIC_MONTHLY_20150802\\samnew.txt");
int count = 0;
try (Reader readerA = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileA));
     Reader readerB = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileB));
     PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileNew))) {
    // Read first line of each file
    String lineA = readerA.readLine();
    String lineB = readerB.readLine();
    // Compare lines
    while (lineA != null || lineB != null) {
        if (lineB == null) {
            // Oops! Found extra line in file A
            lineA = readerA.readLine(); // Read next line from file A
        } else if (lineA == null || ! lineA.equals(lineB)) {
            // Found new line in file B
            writer.println(lineB);
            lineB = readerB.readLine(); // Read next line from file A
            count++;
        } else {
            // Lines are equal, so read next line from both files
            lineA = readerA.readLine();
            lineB = readerB.readLine();
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you read b.txt into a list and then in your code check if each line you read in a.txt is available in the list (list.contains()).